# Add nulls to bigint range PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am filtering values lying in the bigint range using SQL query in PostgreSQL. The issue is that null is not in that range so all the null values are filtered as well which is not what I would like to have in a system.
Here is a current query:

```
select *
from table_test
where '[0,2147483647]'::int8range @> ALL(ARRAY[field1, field2, field3])
```

Input:

```
field1 field2 field3
  1     null   null
  2     null    3  
  3     1000    19
  4      63    3623511495
```

Current output:

```
field1 field2 field3
  3     1000    19
```

Expected output:

```
  1     null   null
  2     null    3  
  3     1000    19
```

How can I add null as possible value to the range of bigint?

Comment: @Cassie . . . Can you construct the `fields` as `coalesce(field1, 0), coalesce(field2, 0)`, . . . .  Also your question is confusing because the range you have specified is the range of the non-negative numbers for a regular 4-byte integer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated the question with examples

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am checking non-negative values which fall into bigint range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use

```
SELECT *
FROM table_test
WHERE '[0,2147483647]'::int8range
      @> ALL(ARRAY[coalesce(field1, 0),
                   coalesce(field2, 0),
                   coalesce(field3, 0)]);
```

just like Gordon Linoff's comment says.

Less cute, but easier to support with indexes would be

```
SELECT *
FROM table_test
WHERE coalesce(field1, 0) BETWEEN 0 AND 2147483647
  AND coalesce(field2, 0) BETWEEN 0 AND 2147483647
  AND coalesce(field3, 0) BETWEEN 0 AND 2147483647;
```